# How to hide plane prefab used for plane detection in ARKit using Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arkit

I am building an app using ARKit for vertical plane detection.Once the plane is detected I need to turn off plane detection.Even after plane is detected it is still tracking and finding more planes.How to turn off when the plane is detected.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

namespace UnityEngine.XR.iOS

{
    public class UnityARHitTestExample : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public Transform m_HitTransform;
        public float maxRayDistance = 30.0f;
    public LayerMask collisionLayer = 1 << 10;  //ARKitPlane layer

    public List<GameObject> Instaobj = new List<GameObject>();

    public Transform ForSelect;
    int Select;
    UnityARCameraManager obj=new UnityARCameraManager();
    UnityARGeneratePlane obb=new UnityARGeneratePlane();


    bool HitTestWithResultType (ARPoint point, ARHitTestResultType resultTypes)
    {
        List<ARHitTestResult> hitResults = UnityARSessionNativeInterface.GetARSessionNativeInterface ().HitTest (point, resultTypes);
        if (hitResults.Count > 0) {
            foreach (var hitResult in hitResults) {
                Debug.Log ("Got hit!");
                obj.Hideplane();
               // obb.planePrefab.SetActive(false);





                m_HitTransform.position = UnityARMatrixOps.GetPosition (hitResult.worldTransform);
                m_HitTransform.rotation = UnityARMatrixOps.GetRotation (hitResult.worldTransform);
                Debug.Log (string.Format ("x:{0:0.######} y:{1:0.######} z:{2:0.######}", m_HitTransform.position.x, m_HitTransform.position.y, m_HitTransform.position.z));








                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {


        #if UNITY_EDITOR   //we will only use this script on the editor side, though there is nothing that would prevent it from working on device
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);
            RaycastHit hit;

            //we'll try to hit one of the plane collider gameobjects that were generated by the plugin
            //effectively similar to calling HitTest with ARHitTestResultType.ARHitTestResultTypeExistingPlaneUsingExtent
            if (Physics.Raycast (ray, out hit, maxRayDistance, collisionLayer)) {
                //we're going to get the position from the contact point
                m_HitTransform.position = hit.point;
                Debug.Log (string.Format ("x:{0:0.######} y:{1:0.######} z:{2:0.######}", m_HitTransform.position.x, m_HitTransform.position.y, m_HitTransform.position.z));

                //and the rotation from the transform of the plane collider
                m_HitTransform.rotation = hit.transform.rotation;
            }
        }
        #else
        if (Input.touchCount > 0 && m_HitTransform != null )
        {
            var touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
            if ((touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began || touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved) &&  !EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject(touch.fingerId))
            {
                var screenPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToViewportPoint(touch.position);
                ARPoint point = new ARPoint {
                    x = screenPosition.x,
                    y = screenPosition.y
                };

                // prioritize reults types
                ARHitTestResultType[] resultTypes = {
                    //ARHitTestResultType.ARHitTestResultTypeExistingPlaneUsingGeometry,
                    ARHitTestResultType.ARHitTestResultTypeExistingPlaneUsingExtent, 
                    // if you want to use infinite planes use this:
                    //ARHitTestResultType.ARHitTestResultTypeExistingPlane,
                    //ARHitTestResultType.ARHitTestResultTypeEstimatedHorizontalPlane, 
                    //ARHitTestResultType.ARHitTestResultTypeEstimatedVerticalPlane, 
                    //ARHitTestResultType.ARHitTestResultTypeFeaturePoint
                }; 

                foreach (ARHitTestResultType resultType in resultTypes)
                {
                    if (HitTestWithResultType (point, resultType))
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        #endif

    }


}
```

}

Below is the UnityARCameraManager

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.XR.iOS;

public class UnityARCameraManager : MonoBehaviour {

    public Camera m_camera;
    private UnityARSessionNativeInterface m_session;
    private Material savedClearMaterial;

    [Header("AR Config Options")]
    public UnityARAlignment startAlignment = UnityARAlignment.UnityARAlignmentGravity;
    public UnityARPlaneDetection planeDetection = UnityARPlaneDetection.Horizontal;
    public ARReferenceImagesSet detectionImages = null;
    public bool getPointCloud = true;
    public bool enableLightEstimation = true;
    public bool enableAutoFocus = true;
    private bool sessionStarted = false;
    private ARKitWorldTrackingSessionConfiguration config;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

    m_session = UnityARSessionNativeInterface.GetARSessionNativeInterface();

    Application.targetFrameRate = 60;
    //ARKitWorldTrackingSessionConfiguration config = new ARKitWorldTrackingSessionConfiguration();
     config = new ARKitWorldTrackingSessionConfiguration();
    config.planeDetection = planeDetection;
    config.alignment = startAlignment;
    config.getPointCloudData = getPointCloud;
    config.enableLightEstimation = enableLightEstimation;
    config.enableAutoFocus = enableAutoFocus;
    if (detectionImages != null) {
        config.arResourceGroupName = detectionImages.resourceGroupName;
    }

    if (config.IsSupported) {
        m_session.RunWithConfig (config);
        UnityARSessionNativeInterface.ARFrameUpdatedEvent += FirstFrameUpdate;
    }

    if (m_camera == null) {
        m_camera = Camera.main;
    }
}

void FirstFrameUpdate(UnityARCamera cam)
{
    sessionStarted = true;
    UnityARSessionNativeInterface.ARFrameUpdatedEvent -= FirstFrameUpdate;
}

public void SetCamera(Camera newCamera)
{
    if (m_camera != null) {
        UnityARVideo oldARVideo = m_camera.gameObject.GetComponent<UnityARVideo> ();
        if (oldARVideo != null) {
            savedClearMaterial = oldARVideo.m_ClearMaterial;
            Destroy (oldARVideo);
        }
    }
    SetupNewCamera (newCamera);
}

private void SetupNewCamera(Camera newCamera)
{
    m_camera = newCamera;

    if (m_camera != null) {
        UnityARVideo unityARVideo = m_camera.gameObject.GetComponent<UnityARVideo> ();
        if (unityARVideo != null) {
            savedClearMaterial = unityARVideo.m_ClearMaterial;
            Destroy (unityARVideo);
        }
        unityARVideo = m_camera.gameObject.AddComponent<UnityARVideo> ();
        unityARVideo.m_ClearMaterial = savedClearMaterial;
    }
}

// Update is called once per frame

void Update () {

    if (m_camera != null && sessionStarted)
    {
        // JUST WORKS!
        Matrix4x4 matrix = m_session.GetCameraPose();
        m_camera.transform.localPosition = UnityARMatrixOps.GetPosition(matrix);
        m_camera.transform.localRotation = UnityARMatrixOps.GetRotation (matrix);

        m_camera.projectionMatrix = m_session.GetCameraProjection ();
    }

}


public void Hideplane()
{

    config.planeDetection = UnityARPlaneDetection.None;

}

}
```

I have tried using the Hideplane() method,still the blue plane is showing
[image: Plane prefab]

I tried this in UnityhittestAR example.I was looking for something like FocusSquare example.Once the plane is detected when we touch the screen the object get placed and no more tracking

Answer (score 0):

Its A temporary solution but it works. In your UnityARKitScene attach a new script

```C#
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
public class EventHandler : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject MainPlane;
    public GameObject DestroyedPlane;
    public GameObject p;
    public int Got;
    private void Start()
    {
        Instantiate(p);
    }
    private void Update()
    {

        MainPlane = GameObject.Find("Plane");
        if(MainPlane!=null){
            if(Got==0){
                MainPlane.name = "MainPlane";
                Got = 1;
            }
            if(Got==1){
                MainPlane = null;
                DestroyedPlane = GameObject.Find("Plane");
                Destroy(DestroyedPlane);
            }
        }
    }
}
```